# Customizing the window popup skin?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to customize the window layouts of popup that opens as a result of window.open event?

Comment: any reason for not using css in the new open window?

Comment: @jebberwocky: it sounds more like he's talking about the window chrome, which CSS doesn't apply to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to style the browser window this is not possible (not reliably across browsers as far as I know at least). You could open up your own-made popups inside the already opened website using javascript (then the popups would not be real popups but elements in the html DOM). Check out www.zkoss.org for an example using ajax for this if you are using java as a backend technology.

Demo:

[Modal window demo](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/window/modal_dialog)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery UI to create a modal dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) if you don't need an actual browser window.